# C3P0 connection provider creates new connection or reuse connection?

Tags: java, database, c3p0

I am facing some use related to `GET_LOCK` in MySQL. I am using `c3p0` connection provider. Does `getConnection()` method in `c3P0` create new connection every time or reuse the connection?

Answer (score 1):

getConnection on DataSource gets the connection from connection pool. If there isn't any available and maxPoolSize isn't reached then it opens new connection. If the maxPoolSize is reached then it waits for some connection to return to the pool. (it must be released by the thread which is using it)

After the thread releases the connection then it is returned to the pool and might be reused by some other thread.

The documentation is http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Answer (score 0):

c3p0 maintains a pool of Connections, which are reused for multiple clients.

however, you cannot make any assumption that a Connection you use will be the same Connection you will see again. you might receive any Connection from c3p0's pool, there's no guarantee or likelihood you'll see one you've already seen. and, depending on your configuration, c3p0 tests, expires, and replaces Connections behind the scenes.

if you are trying to associate a lock with a Connection in one client session and then release it in another, well, that won't work and will break things fast. really, with any explicit locking, your acquisition and release should be done in one client session, using try / finally semantics to ensure lock release.